# Node.JS Prepared Statement with (INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... SELECT) MySQL Event

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to add a mySQL Event. First below you'll see my initial setup for my values.

```
payload.TierKeys.forEach(t => {
            queryArrays.push([
                CREATE_KEY(),
                t,
                payload.PageKey,
                payload.StoryKey,
                'NOW()',
                `(SELECT Chapters.ChapterKey FROM Chapters INNER JOIN PublishingQueue ON Chapters.ChapterKey = PublishingQueue.ChapterKey WHERE Chapters.StoryKey = ${escape(payload.StoryKey)} ORDER BY Chapters.ChapterOrder ASC LIMIT 1)`,
            ]);
        });
```

Then after I set up those values, I use them in the following query.

```
pool.query(`
                CREATE EVENT ${queryData.ScheduleKey + i}
                    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS ?
                    DO
                        INSERT INTO PublishRecord (PublishRecordKey, TierKey, PageKey, StoryKey, PublishDate, ChapterKey) VALUES ?
            `, [dateISO, queryArrays], (err, rows, fields) => {
```

Then the problem is that the statement is prepared as only strings. You can see here the actual DO clause that node prepares:

```
(INSERT INTO PublishRecord (PublishRecordKey, TierKey, PageKey, StoryKey, PublishDate, ChapterKey) VALUES ('lc0qgw7uly', 'lbz602e5js', 'lbz527cfjm', 'lbz74fw5zl', 'NOW()', '(SELECT Chapters.ChapterKey FROM Chapters INNER JOIN PublishingQueue ON Chapters.ChapterKey = PublishingQueue.ChapterKey WHERE Chapters.StoryKey = 'lbz74fw5zl' ORDER BY Chapters.ChapterOrder ASC LIMIT 1)')
```

See how the `(SELECT...` is wrapped in single quotes? And the `NOW()` is also wrapped in single quotes. That should not be the case. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

There were other issues with my query, but I fixed the prepared statement ... by not using prepared statements :-)

Instead I'm creating the string beforehand, interpolating the values in and escaping them as they are interpolated. This succeeds. So it's still sort-of a prepared statement, but my own solution.